# What kind of weapons did the IG-227 Hailfire droid have?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, weapon, droids, trade-federation

According to a Star Wars encyclopedia, in between the two wheels that make up the [Hailfire](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/IG-227_Hailfire-class_droid_tank) droid is a small "weapons unit". But it never said *what* kinds of weapons were in the "weapons unit". So what kinds of weapons does it have?

[image]

https://www.starwars.com/databank/hailfire-droid

Comment: @NKCampbell tysm for the edit. I love the picture you added. :)   o_o;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**15 guided missiles x 2**

> **HAILFIRE DROID**
> Engineering MODEL IG-227 Hailfire-class droid tank
>
> The IG-227 Hailfire-class droid tank is easily
> identified by its treaded, hoop-like drive
> wheels. The InterGalactic Banking Clan
> commissioned the construction of the hailfire
> prior to the Clone Wars, and the units saw
> their first combat against Republic troops
> during the Battle of Geonosis. **A hailfire is
> an armored missile platform best used to
> destroy enemy vehicles. Each of the two
> launchers mounted on a hailfire can hold
> up to 15 guided missiles.**
>
> **Rolling into battle**
>
> The hailfire is also called the wheel droid
> due to its maneuverable and speedy drive
> system (below). Each missile from the
> droid leaves behind a trail of black
> exhaust that darkens the sky (right).
>
> <sub><sup>[Ultimate Star Wars](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ultimate_Star_Wars)</sup></sub>

It also sports what the [*'Rise of the Separatists'* RPG sourcebook](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rise_of_the_Separatists) refers to as a

> "forward-mounted twin auto-blaster"